# I'm having issues using keras's expand_dims function

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm having issues using keras's expand_dims function

```
import os
import glob
import random
import datetime
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from PIL import Image
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.utils import img_to_array
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix, classification_report

img_tensor = img_to_array(imgs)
img_tensor = expand_dims(img_tensor, 0)

img_tensor /=255

plt.figure(figsize=(3, 4))
plt.imshow(img_tensor[0])
plt.show()
```

with the caption "name 'expand_dims' is not defined"

can you help me where is the error?

Comment: Use tf.expand_dims

Comment: Nowhere you imported a function called expand_dims

Answer (score 0):

As correctly mentioned by @Innat, You need to use [tf.expand_dims()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) or [np.expand_dims()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) to expand the array dimensions.
Please check the code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
img_data = np.random.random(size=(100, 100, 3))
img = tf.keras.utils.array_to_img(img_data)
array = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
img_tensor = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(img)
img_tensor.shape  #Output:(100, 100, 3)
```

using **tf.expand_dims()**

```
img_tensor = tf.expand_dims(img_tensor, 0)
img_tensor.shape
```

Output: `(1, 100, 100, 3)`

Or can use **numpy.expand_dims()**

```
img_tensor = np.expand_dims(img_tensor, 0)
img_tensor.shape
```

Output: `(1, 100, 100, 3)`